# Adjusting height in scrollView

Tags: angularjs, height, famo.us

I created scrollView contains multiple surfaces, i'd like them to be aligned under each other without declaring static height for them as "fa-size="[undefined, 100]", the app is resizeable on different mobile devices (that's why i made the width "undefined"), so the true parameter in fa-size should do, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

code:

```
     <fa-app  style="height:570px;" >
        <fa-scroll-view  fa-pipe-from="eventHandler"
                fa-options="options.myScrollView">

        <fa-modifier  fa-size="[undefined,true]"> 
          <fa-surface fa-pipe-to="eventHandler" >
            <div>Content1</div>
          </fa-surface>
        </fa-modifier>

        <fa-modifier  fa-size="[undefined,true]"> 
          <fa-surface fa-pipe-to="eventHandler" >
            <div>Content2</div>
          </fa-surface>
        </fa-modifier>

       </fa-scroll-view>
     </fa-app>
```

that's the result :

[image]

I made another approach, i created on surface contains all the divs contents and the "fa-size="[undefined, undefined]"" in order to show all the contents contained and under each other smoothly, they're relative to each other now but the height overflows at the end of the scrollView, height as "true" should make this work fine but it doesn't work too.

code :

```
     <fa-app  style="height:570px;" >
        <fa-scroll-view  fa-pipe-from="eventHandler" 
                 fa-options="options.myScrollView">

        <fa-modifier  fa-size="[undefined,undefined]"> 
          <fa-surface fa-pipe-to="eventHandler" >

            <div>Content1</div>
            <div>Content2</div>

          </fa-surface>
        </fa-modifier>

        </fa-scroll-view>
     </fa-app>
```

Note : I tried to change the clipSize and using sequentialLayout but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

They're overlapping because you need to apply Translate to each surface you want moved